# How to do a if else statement in classic asp

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, asp-classic

I'm new to classic asp and I'm trying to figure out this simple if else statement.
For some reason it's just recognizing person 2 and not even trying person 1?

Any idea on how to fix? Thanks

This is my code:

```
<%
Dim GetPath
GetPath = request.ServerVariables("URL") & query_string

Dim page
page = "/products/dowlex/index.htm"

if GetPath = page then
    varrecipient = "email1@email.com"
    Response.Write("*Path = " & GetPath)
    Response.Write("Person 1")
else
    varrecipient = "email2@email.com"
    Response.Write("*Path = " & GetPath)
    Response.Write("Person 2")
end if

varFormName = "Contact"
varRHBusinessUnit = "businessname"
varLanguage = "ENGLISH"
varCourtesyResponse = "Y"
varRedirect = "#noredir?formRun=true"
varSubject = "Ask an Expert Form"
%>
```

Comment: Just a guess, but those variable names look like they might be reserved words. Try using strange variable names instead of GetPath and page.

Comment: It was suppose to be a variable for the path. I used to have it like [ 
if GetPath = "/products/dowlex/index.htm" then  ]

Comment: but "GetPath" is blue, and "page" is not ... so one of them is probably a reserved word.  (Maybe.) Like I said, it's just a guess, but it's a simple thing to test! :)

Comment: but even when I used it the other way it still didn't work. it not even comparing the pages to make sure it no the page specified. it automatically goes to person2.

Comment: I've started add my "comments" as "answers" below, so people can give them an up-vote if they like them. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would compare the two strings based on the same case...

if UCase(GetPath) = UCase(page) then

And of course, if query_string ever has a value, then the 1st case will never be true.

Comment: Is this something I should still remove? If so, how would I rewrite this?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure why exactly you are appending the querystring to determine if it is the same as "/products/dowlex/index.htm"

If you just want to see if you are on that index.htm page, I would remove the string concat of the query_string.  Then you would only be checking if the current page they are viewing is that index.htm page.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple thoughts.

1) Can you use Response.Write to display what's in "GetPath" before the if statement?  That might help you see what's going wrong!

2) Try changing the variable names.  The editor is making "GetPath" blue, as though it's a reserved word.  That might be messing things up.

Comment: This actually helped me fix my mistake. It wasn't the GetPath, but it was the page variable. I forgot to add the 2 folders in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

The formatting of your statement is fine. If... Then... Else... End if.

I would do a Response.Write("GetPath") to see if you are getting back, what you think you should be.

Comment: This actually helped me fix my mistake. It wasn't the GetPath, but it was the page variable. I forgot to add the 2 folders in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry guys, I messed up a small code and thats why it wasn't working.
I forgot to complete the full path of the site. Thanks for all your help and suggestions!

```
*Path = /plasticpipes/eu/products/dowlex/index.htm
*Page = /products/dowlex/index.htm
```